# scroll-snap no css não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: css, html5, css3, rolamento

Estou criando uma página em html e estou tendo o seguinte problema:
Precisei utilizar o método `scroll-snap` do css para 'travar' uma div a cada rolagem do mouse. Esse 'snap' está funcionando com um porém, quando 'rolo' o scroll do mouse ele trava na segunda div abaixo da que estou, ao invés de travar na próxima, como se executasse duas vezes.
Segue o código:

```css
html {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.item {
    height: 80vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    border-bottom: black thin solid;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM 4</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM 5</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tente colocar `scroll-snap-stop: always;` e testa, se der certo me fala que posto como resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Está funcionando normalmente para mim. Eu creio que a rolagem esteja pulando elementos para você por conta da "força" do rolamento - você desliza e a quantidade de pixels que o container *scrollado* se move é maior que o tamanho do próximo elemento, então o snap acaba caindo no próximo.

A velocidade/força do scroll (quantidade de pixels que o container se move no rolamento) depende de vários fatores e realmente não é algo da página, então realmente não é simples você conseguir ter o controle disto - principalmente com elementos mais baixos como o do exemplo.

Uma solução que posso sugerir seria você usar o javascript recriar o efeito de scroll e ter o controle do *quão rápido* o usuário vai poder *scrollar* - você iria bloquear o evento padrão à rolagem do usuário e mover o container manualmente na "força" que você quiser.

```
// "pixels por rolamento" (a velocidade que o usuário irá scrollar)
const speed = 50;

window.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  // anula o scroll padrão do browser
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // verifica se o usuário está rolando para cima ou para baixo e
  // executa a função customizada adequada
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    scrollingDown();
  } else {
    scrollingUp();
  }

},{ passive: false });
// a propriedade passive, resumidamente, diz se o navegador irá ou
// não "ignorar" a preventDefault() do listener. Esta propriedade é
// definida por padrão como true para alguns eventos de scroll em
// alguns navegadores, então é preciso atribuir "false" a ela.
// +: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

// aqui pega a posição atual da janela
let currentScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

// funções customizadas para recriar o efeito de scroll
function scrollingDown() {
  currentScrollPosition += speed;
  window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition);
}

function scrollingUp() {
  currentScrollPosition -= speed;
  window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition);
}

// este código se baseia no scroll da janela (window), mas você pode
// implementar em um elemento específico
```

**[ATENÇÃO]:** Recomendo esta solução para situação onde realmente não tenha mais saída, isto pode comprometer a experiência do usuário drasticamente! Evite-a ao máximo e antes de decidir realmente implementá-la, explore outras alternativas para o seu problema!

Answer (score -1):

Existem algumas possíveis causas para esse comportamento. Uma delas é que o atributo "scroll-snap-type" está sendo aplicado na tag "html" em vez de na tag "body". Isso pode estar causando o "snap" a ser aplicado em toda a página, em vez de apenas no conteúdo dentro do elemento "container".

Outra possibilidade é que o elemento "container" não está tendo o tamanho correto para acomodar todo o conteúdo. Isso pode estar causando o scroll a continuar rolando além do elemento "container" e, portanto, "snapping" na div seguinte.

Eu sugiro verificar se esses problemas estão ocorrendo e corrigi-los. Se esses problemas não estiverem presentes, então é possível que haja algum outro elemento ou atributo que está causando esse comportamento indesejado. Eu sugiro verificar o código completo da página e procurar por qualquer outro elemento ou atributo que possa estar interferindo na funcionalidade de "snap".